# C# ref return a ref return

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, c#-10.0

I'm trying to make an `ref return` method that returns another `ref return` method, but can't get it working **if the methods take in a `ref` parameter**

Here is the example code:

```
public class TestRef
{
    public int storage=42;


    public ref int Get(ref bool someParam)
    {
        return ref this.storage;
    }

    public ref int Get2(bool someParam)
    {
        var someParam2 = someParam;
        ref var result =ref Get(ref someParam2);

        return ref result;
    }

}
```

Doing this I see the following error on the bottom `return ref result;` line:
`Error  CS8157  Cannot return 'result' by reference because it was initialized to a value that cannot be returned by reference`

However this code works:

```
public class TestRef
{
    public int storage=42;


    public ref int Get()
    {
        return ref this.storage;
    }

    public ref int Get2()
    {
        ref var result =ref Get();
        return ref result;
    }

}
```

What am I doing wrong here?  How can I return the result by-ref?

Comment: `Get` doesn't actually mutate the parameter, so why are you passing it by ref in the first place?  Just don't do that if you have no reason to.

Comment: To provide a repro/example as simply as possible.

Comment: Strongly consider whether you want to mutate parameters. In general, you want to avoid side effects.

Comment: I'm not mutating parameters.   passing by ref is a performance optimization.     Please don't get caught up in how trivial the `ref bool someParam` is.   This is just a simple example of the problem.

Comment: @JasonS Passing such a parameter by reference is likely to make it perform *worse*, not better.  It's only likely to be helpful for performance if the parameter being passed is large (which you should avoid whenever possible, for exactly that reason).  If not passing a parameter that doesn't have a good reason to be passed by ref solves your problem, *then it has solved your problem*.  Remember that examples should be sufficiently representative of the actual problem, not just as simple as possible to the point of obscuring the actual problem.

Comment: Thank you, but I realize these things Servy.  I tried to simplify the problem down to it's most basic parts so we wouldn't get caught up in ancillary issues like "why am I doing that".   I am building a system that requires extreme optimization in some parts.   Not all parts, but ensuring this `ref` "tool" works is important for optimizing critical path when I need to.

Comment: @JasonS If the performance is really that important then it's all the more important to not use `ref`.  Managing the reference is going to be slower than copying a bit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the ["ref returns" (C# 7.0) champion](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/58) links to [this article](http://mustoverride.com/safe-to-return/) which lists next "safe to return" rules:

- refs to variables on the heap are safe to return
- ref parameters are safe to return
- out parameters are safe to return (but must be definitely assigned, as is already the case today)
- instance struct fields are safe to return as long as the receiver is safe to return
- “this” is not safe to return from struct members
- a ref, returned from another method is safe to return if all refs/outs passed to that method as formal parameters were safe to return.

Your code violates the last one - because local variable `someParam2` is not safe to return. Either make `Get` accepting `bool someParam` or make `someParam` of `Get2` `ref bool` and remove the local assignment (`ref var someParam2 = ref someParam;` will also work):

```
public ref int Get2(ref bool someParam)
{
    ref var result = ref Get(ref someParam);

    return ref result;
}
```

Imagine if `someParam` would be an `int` then you could make:

```
ref int Get(ref int i)
{
     return ref i;
}
```

which will make the following:

```
ref int Get2(...)
{
     int local = 1; 
     return ref Get(ref local);
}
```

doing something very wrong.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I don't think this is a valid answer.  `someParam2` isn't returned.  it shoudn't matter for the return of `Get2()`

Comment: @JasonS it does not matter - those are listed as rules to determine "safe to return" status. `someParam2`  is passed to `ref` parameter of `Get` and is a local variable on stack so it is not a safe to return one.

Comment: @JasonS and it at least partially makes sense. Imagine if `someParam` would be `int` then you could make `Get(ref int i){return ref i;}` which will make `Get2(...){int local = 1; return ref Get(ref local);}` doing something very wrong.

Comment: Okay thank you, that last comment makes sense.  I suggest you add that to your answer!   I'll accept it!  (and upvote of course)